# WSO2 IoT server fail to download device agent

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, wso2, iot

I have downloaded WSO2 IoT server version 3.0.0, and followed all the instructions to run the product on Windows 10 machine with JDK 1.8 installed. Everything was going fine until I tried to download virtual fire alarm device agent.

Simple, it was not working, and a blank page with no response was all that I have got. Then I tried the same for a Raspberry Pi device, and again the device agent failed to be downloaded. It is interesting that this bug was reported for Alpha and 3.1.0 product versions, so it seemed that the current official version is free from this.

Do you have any explanation of this ill behavior (it doesn't seem to me that anything is missing in the documentation)?

Comment: I strongly believe there's an issue / misconfiguration related to the logon (authentication) redirect, if you find an aswear meanwhile, please comment :)

Comment: do you get any exception?, if so please share.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now [https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/issues/1134](https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/issues/1134). 
You may wait for the next immediate release or else you can clone the repos and build yourselves.